# How to rename the files in all subdirectory with the name of that subdirectory?

Tags: linux, bash

I've files like this:

```
all/01/data.xml
all/02/data.xml
all/03/data.xml
```

I want to copy all the `data.xml`s into the `all` directory.

Of course I can do this by `find -exec` and `for`. However the problem is that all the files are with the same name and the later will overwrite the previous ones.

So I want to rename the file with the subdirectory name.

How do I do that with Bash? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in */data.xml; do mv $f  `basename $f .xml``dirname $f`.xml; done
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, assuming all your data.xml files are only 1 subdir deep;

```
$ cd all
$ for x in */data.xml
> do
> f=`echo $x | sed -e 's/\//_/'`
> mv $x $f
> done
```

Comment: you must've meant `$f` and not `#f`